# How do i generate all the permutations of the first n letters from the alphabet, lexicographically?

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation

Find a method to generate all the permutations of the first n letters from the alphabet, lexicographically, but ignore the results which have two vocals standing next to each other.
I tried this, but for some testcases it appears to be wrong, and also, it's very slow on others so I can't tell if it worked on those.. It works for a few cases only..
**Input**:

4
**output**

```
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
adbc
adcb
bacd
badc
bcad
bcda
bdac
bdca
cabd
cadb
cbad
cbda
cdab
cdba
dabc
dacb
dbac
dbca
dcab
dcba
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n;
bool verify(char sir[9]) {
    char v[] = "aeiou";
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        char *p = strchr(v, sir[i]);
        if(p != 0) {
             p = strchr(v, sir[i - 1]);
            if(p != 0)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int lg = 0;
    char sir[9];
    cin >> n;
    for (char c = 'a'; c < 'a' + n; ++c) {
        sir[lg] = c;
        ++lg;
    }
    do {
        if(verify(sir)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                cout << sir[i] << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
        }
    } while(next_permutation(sir, sir + n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I reviewed your code it a bit: [**Sample on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ad915629cce240a). However, I suspect that a modified `next_permutation()` could do even better. E.g. imagine the case (for input 5) `aebcd`. The next step might be `aebdc` but actually the whole sequence starting with `ae` can be skipped.

Comment: Btw. for input 4, there can never be two vocals next to each other. :-) Just an observation...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You're right, I was too lazy to write an example with the first 5 permutations.. If you wanna, you could post the comment as an answer and I'll give it a checkmark ;)